# How to cancel any movement of Google Map?

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

I have somewhere in my application called `map.animateCamera(...)`.

I want to cancel *ANY* movement of the map. I am looking for something like `map.cancelCameraMove()` or something similar, but unfortunately, it does not exist.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems [`map.stopAnimation()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#stopAnimation()) is what you need:

```
...
map.animateCamera(location, duration, null);
...

// when need to stop animation
map.stopAnimation();
```

Or you can use workaround: get current camera position via [`map.getCameraPosition()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#getCameraPosition()) and move it instantaneous exactly to them with [`map.moveCamera()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#moveCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)). Something like that:

```
...
map.animateCamera(location, duration, null);
...

// when need to stop animation
CameraPosition cameraPosition = map.getCameraPosition();
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Comment: Your first solution send to still call onfinish in the call back. Any workaround

Comment: @j2emanue You need to call `onFinish()` of `GoogleMap.CancelableCallback`?

Comment: try for yourself, call map.stopAnimation() and notice that onFinish() still gets called, onCancel is not called.  looks like a bug.

Comment: @j2emanue on my side with `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.+'` everything is fine: `onCancel()` called after `map.stopAnimation();`, `onFinish()` - without `map.stopAnimation();` call. Anyway, I know a workaround too. Please crate new question.

Comment: its ok. i just put in a boolean to check ..its not too hard.. not worth the extra effort. thanks though.